# Refresh header component after login

Tags: angular

My application uses identity server and I'm storing the user's name in a session variable once redirected back.

The name is not displaying, it will only if I refresh the page. How can correct this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.css"]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks: any[];
  activeLinkIndex = -1;
  displayName: string;
  logoutUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.navLinks = [
      {
        label: "Projects",
        link: "project-list",
        index: 0
      }
    ];    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(res => {
      this.activeLinkIndex = this.navLinks.indexOf(
        this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link === "." + this.router.url)
      );
    });

    this.displayName = sessionStorage.getItem("displayName");
    this.logoutUrl = environment.oidc_post_logout_redirect_uri;
  }
}

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{ displayName }}</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't said how you are performing the login, so for the purposes of this answer I'm going to assume you're making a call in a service called `loginService`.

You could create a subject in your login service that emits a value every time the authentication status changes. Every time the user logs in or out, the login service would emit a new value informing subscribers of the new status.

All interested components, such as the header component, can subscribe to that subject to receive updates about the login status.

**login service**

```
// I am using a replay subject here to ensure new subscribers get the current status
private loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

login(): Observable<boolean> {
  // TODO: set up http request
  return this.http.post(loginUrl, body).pipe(
    tap(() => this.loggedIn.next(true)
  );
}

logout(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.post(loginUrl, body).pipe(
    tap(() => this.loggedIn.next(false)
  );
}

loginStatusChange(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}
```

**header component**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loginService.loginStatusChange().subscribe(loggedIn => {
    // TODO: apply logic based on logged in status
  });
}
```

This is very simplistic, and only focusses on the aspect of the design pattern. I have ignored the kind of implementation detail that you would normally add, such as error handling and unsubscribing from the subject.